# The utility mysql is not accessible

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL utilities installed on my computer. When I type the following command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root
```

and I'm getting the following message:

```
The utility mysql is not accessible (
from the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities).
```

Is there a reason why I'm getting this error message?

Comment: Is mysql.exe actually in the utilities folder?

Comment: No I have mysqluc.. Could that be a problem?

Comment: mySQL utilities seem to be distinct from the actual mySQL server. You may need to install that

Comment: to run commands which start with mysql, you need to use mysql.exe which is located in {mysql.istallation.directory}\bin

Comment: MySQL utilities is an old Python 2.6 package.  It must be installed separately.   For more information see:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-utilities.html